# Hide useless Extensions icons in Chrome

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I am using Debian Buster, and I have upgraded Chromium from version 83 to 90.

Now, in addition to the individual Extensions icons, there is also new icon for managing the extension:

[image]

This is completely unnecessary and idiotic.

Extensions can be managed from the settings menu, why would I need yet another dedicated extra icon for "quick access" ?

Is there any way I can remove/hide this icon?

Speaking of idiotic useless icons, is there any way to disable the "playback" icon that appears when playing any audio/video? That is the icon on the right from the extension icon.

Comment: I would try chrome://flags/ in the URL bar and maybe there is a setting there for this... I'm not familiar if there is a setting there, but might be worth trying if that button bothers you that much

Comment: @al1en - thanks. Any idea how such option would be called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to hide the Extensions jigsaw icon has now been deprecated.

The option used to exist in the flag `chrome:flags#extensions-toolbar-menu`,
then was removed by the developers.

Then it still existed as an argument on the Chrome invocation
as `--disable-features=ExtensionsToolbarMenu`,
then was also removed by the developers.

Nowadays it still exists as an argument on the Chrome invocation,
but it only works in Incognito mode (don't ask why),
so the Chrome call needs to be:

```
\path\to\chrome-executable --Incognito --disable-features=ExtensionsToolbarMenu
```

I tested, and this works for the moment, but it removes **all** extension
icons and enlarges the address field appropriately.

So it seems that the jigsaw icon is here to stay.